# How to authenticate specific route to user with specific role in laravel Milldeware

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I have multiple users with multiple permissions. A user can belong to the only single role but that role can have multiple permissions like `create`, `read`, `update`, `delete`. And I have a `RoleMiddleware`. I am authenticating the user in `roleMiddleware`. But how can I protect `routes` in `RoleMiddleware` against a specific user?

For Example, I have a route `create-case` which can only be accessed by the `operator` or by `Admin` else everyone redirects to `404 error` how Can I deal with it in `RoleMiddleware`.

I have written basic code for authentication where every user with their roles is authenticated but I am getting how can I code in middleware so ever route when a user hits it may go to the `RoleMiddleware` where middleware `Authenticate` route to the Role and then give him the access.

Role Middleware

```
class RoleMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $permission = null)
    {

        if (Auth::check() === false)
        {
            return redirect('login');
        }
        elseif (Auth::check() === true)
        {
            $roles = Role::all()->pluck('slug');

            if (is_null($request->user()) )
            {
                abort(404);
            }
            if (!$request->user()->hasRole($roles))
            {
                abort(404);
            }

            if ($request->user())
            {
                if ($request->user()->hasRole($roles))
                {
                    return $next($request);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Case Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Cases;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\CaseStoreRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Session;

class CaseController extends Controller
{
    use DropzoneFileUploadTraits;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('role');

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['portal'] = Portal::all();
        $data['operators'] = Operator::all();

        return view('case', $data);
    }

    public function caseList()
    {
        $user = new User();
        $isAdmin = $user->isAdmin();

        $loggedIn = Auth::id();

        $cases = Cases::with('patients', 'portal')
            ->when(!$isAdmin, function ($query) use ($loggedIn) {
                return $query->where('user_id', $loggedIn);
            })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        $data['cases'] = $cases;

        return view('case_list', $data);
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('create-case', 'Cases\CaseController@index')->name('create-case');
Route::post('case-submit', 'Cases\CaseController@caseSubmit')->name('case-submit');
Route::post('edit-patient-case-submit', 'Cases\CaseController@editPatientCaseSubmit')->name('edit-patient-case-submit');
Route::get('case-list', 'Cases\CaseController@caseList')->name('case-list');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do that in a clean manner would be to create policies on the targeted entities.
Laravel policies allow you to :

- Bind a route authorization logic to a policy action
- Easily call a policy action result from anywhere else in the project (views, controllers and so on).

The subject is well covered in Laravel documentation so I suggest you go there and take a look. Do not forget to register the policy and bind it to your model.

Apart from that this should do the trick.

```html
class CasePolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function create(User $user){
        $roles = ['operator','Admin']
        return $user->hasRole($roles);
    }
}
```

Then in your route file :

```html
Route::get('create-case', 'Cases\CaseController@index')->name('create-case')->middleware('can:create,App\Case');
```

Comment: i have answered my question using your help it is working for me. Kindly do check it if i wrote the code right logically and is this the way we use gate and policies

Answer (score 0):

I haved just learned and implement Gate and Policy hope this is correct Because its working for me. Great concept thanks.

```
Route::get('create-case', 'Cases\CaseController@index')->name('create-case')->middleware('can:create-case,App\Model\Case');
```

Gate:

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',

        User::class => CreateCase::class

    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Gate::define('create-case','App\Policies\CreateCase@create_case');

    }
}
```

Policy

```
class CreateCase
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Create a new policy instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function create_case(User $user){

        if($user->hasRole(['admin']) ||$user->hasRole(['operator']) && $user->hasPermissionTo('create')){

            return true;
        }else
            return false;

    }
}
```